# can't load index.html after refresh and if I use `/*` or `*` in server side render the page will crash (aww, snap!) angularjs express nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

so, I it's happen when I add `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true,requireBase: false,rewriteLinks: true});`. in the first load it's run successfuly, but when I refresh my page, index.html won't load and only load the content of the page

so there in my code

ngroute in angularjs

```
home.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$httpProvider)
{
  //    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('*');

    $routeProvider.when('/home',
    {
         templateUrl: 'home.html',

    })
    .when('/access_level',
    {
         templateUrl: 'access_level.html',

    })
    .when('/Users',
    {
        templateUrl: 'Users.html',

    })
    .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/home'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true,requireBase: false,rewriteLinks: true});
 });
```

routing express(app.js)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index'); //untuk menampilkan route page index 
}); 
app.get('/:name',function(req,res){
   var name = req.params.name;
   res.render(name);
});
```

so, thank you for every help for this problem, I appreciate it

before refresh
[image]

after refresh
[image]

**Update**

I already try using from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode but it's not working, the page keep crash every 5 second (crash message is : "Aw, Snap!")

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
// Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
   res.sendFile('/views/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
app.get('/:name',function(req,res){
   var name = req.params.name;
   res.render(name);
});
```

**page crash / Aw, Snap!**

[image]

everytime I use `'/*'` or `'*'` the page gonna crash. so, what's should I do?

finaly I found another solution, even I didn't use html5 mode in angularjs, but it's work

so, I only make views folder work's like public folder

change from

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

and then I only create / server side route (I didn't need `/:name` anymore)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/views/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Comment: You're mixing server-side and client-side routes. When you request `/home`, your backend is intercepting via the `/:name` route and showing `home.html` only.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode - **Express Rewrites**

Comment: I already try it, but the page wont show content from /home and the page crash ("Aw, Snap!" page crashes) @Phil